# Elegant and robust replacement of characters in substring only

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am looking for an elegant and robust way to replace characters that are contained between `" "`

The replacement is : `,` **becomes** `.` **if contained within** `" "`.
E.g I have this string:

> The red, fox jumps over the "lazy,dog"

I would like this to become

> The red, fox jumps over the "lazy.dog"

I am aware that `replace()` is a native JS function that can replace characters in a string but I am baffled as to how to achieve the above.

The only way I can currently think of is a bit complex, and it involves a `FOR` loop to iterate over the string and `IF/ELSE's.`

What would be an elegant and robust way to achieve this?

Comment: Use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) as the first argument for `replace`.

Comment: wouldn't that replace only the first instance of the matching regEx?

Comment: Reading the linked article reveals `g` flag ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex (*which uses [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*) to  replace `,` present inside the `"` with `.`,

```
> 'The red, fox jumps over the "lazy,dog" foo,bar foo "bar,foo" "lazy,dog" ,foo'.replace(/,(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g, ".");
'The red, fox jumps over the "lazy.dog" foo,bar foo "bar.foo" "lazy.dog" ,foo'
```

Comment: Why not, but it makes the regex engine hardly work since for each comma found, the engine needs to check the string from the current position until the end.

Comment: you mean i need to add a possesive quantifier like this `,(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*+[^"]*$)` or `,(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*+")*+[^"]*$)`

Comment: No, It doesn't change nothing to add a possessive quantifier. Imagine a 50 chars length string with a `,` all the 10 chars. When you find the first `,` at position 10, the lookahead needs to check 40 chars after. When you find the second, 30 chars, etc. For a global search the lookahead has parsed 40+30+20+10 = 100 chars. The same with a 100 chars length string => 900 chars, 200 => 3800, 500 => 24500, 1000 => 99000... *(a book page has about 1500 chars => 223500)* you see the probem. However, for not too long strings this approach will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a callback.

```
var r = 'The red, fox jumps over the "lazy,dog"'.replace(/"[^"]+"/g, function(v) { 
      return v.replace(/,/g, '.');
}); // The red, fox jumps over the "lazy.dog"
```

Comment: Why do you group the whole regex in parens?

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log('  hello, ",  sdad, "  '.replace(/".+?"/g,function(e){return e.replace(/\,/g,".")}))
```

Comment: Do you realize that [\s\S] will match ANY character? Use a dot, if that's what you really mean. Also, why are you needlessly escaping characters that aren't special characters (quotes, commas)?

Comment: [\s\S] will match any character, but ? will make it lazy and the function will match the least ammount of text until the next.  see this: http://www.regexr.com/39dmr

Comment: Yes, the ? makes it lazy. So use ".+?"

Comment: @BrianStephens: `.+?` is different from `[\s\S]+?` since the first one doesn't match newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var regex = /".*"/,
    text = 'The red, fox jumps over the "lazy,dog"';

    console.log(text.replace(regex, function(match) { return match.replace(/,/g, '.'); }));
```

More info on Regex with function at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: That modifier is greedy. You will match from the first quote to the last.